# How to redeclare package in a model before making an instance?

Tags: modelica

I would like to do

```
    M_type(redeclare package L=L2) m2_instance;
```

but does not work. Instead I can write

```
    model M2_type
       extends M_type(redeclare package L=L2);
    end M2_type;
    M2_type m2_instance;
```

Is here not a shorter way to do this and avoid declaring M2_type?

Comment: All should work, including M_type m2_instance(redeclare package L=L2); alternatives: model M2_type = M_type(redeclare package L=L2); M2_type m2_instance;

Comment: Why M_type(redeclare package L=L2) m2_instance; doesn't work? What is the error?

Comment: Never mind, of course M_type(redeclare package L=L2) m2_instance; is not syntactically correct. https://specification.modelica.org/maint/3.5/modelica-concrete-syntax.html, type-specifier:   ["."] name. I should not answer questions on Friday :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The redeclare modifier must be moved to the instance name.

```
M_type(redeclare package L=L2) m2_instance;  // wrong syntax
M_type m2_instance(redeclare package L=L2);  // correct
```

Below is a small package, which demonstrates everything and simulates perfectly fine in Dymola 2021x and OpenModelica 1.16.2.

```
package Redeclaration
  package L1
    constant Real x = 1;
  end L1;

  package L2
    constant Real x = 2;
  end L2;

  model M_type
    replaceable package L = L1;
    Real x = L.x;
  end M_type;
  
  model Example
    M_type m_instance(redeclare package L=L2);
  end Example;
end Redeclaration;
```